# Best practice to handle right click tooltip in AngularJS way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

RIght now, I need to load some image into page, for each image, if I right click on it, it will show a tooltip of its info such as size and description. I implement the image as a directive, but I do not know how to handle the right click correctly, any suggestion for best practice( any example is appreciated)?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle right-click events in angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js)

Comment: @Donal Thanks, I am gonna try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a directive for the images, you should be able just to do the following in the link function of your directive:

```
link:function(scope, elem){
    elem.bind('contextmenu', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert('success!'); //Show tooltip here
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, I think my crucial question should be how to structure that tooltip directive( should I add tooltip into each image directive structure or make a seperated tooltip directive? )  and how to manage its behavior or event responds

Comment: It depends on the tooltip. Is it a very specific tooltip to one type of component(directive)? If so, make it part of the directive. If you intend to use the same tooltip for many different situations, I'd make a specific `tooltip` directive which you use by decorating other elements. You could use how https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip is implemented for a good pattern.

Comment: thanks, it is the first case. I guess then I just need to figure out the style issue.

Comment: Also, as an aside, showing a tooltip on rightclick might be nonintuitive. What if they wanted to right click -> save as? Tooltips make more sense as a mouseover.

Comment: thanks, my bad, I should call it right click menu rather than tooltip, but it is just a name, we know what I mean.