# AngularJS: detecting mouse left click?

Tags: angularjs

I tried this modified version of jquery function:

```
$scope.link_clicked = function(e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
        $("#spinner_bg").css("display", "block");
    }
};
```

But it gives error: "Cannot read property 'button' of undefined..." :/

Comment: Use directive instead of jquery. This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js

Comment: There's not enough code here to help. Show us where you set this function  as the event listener.
Also, are you looking for angular help, or jQuery help?

Comment: for angularjs, it's inside of the controller, on the link there is this code: ng-click="link_clicked()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the `$event` object: `ng-click=link_clicked($event)` like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6syrqg6/).

The JS code:

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
.controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.link_clicked  = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
}]);
```