# call function when users click on "open link in new tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angularjs. In my application i have one link say(opentab).I have added ng-click event on this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="clickevent()">opentab</a>
```

I want when users right click on "opentab" and select "open link in new tab" it call clickevent function

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? If it is to detect all cases of user trying to open link in new tab, just checking for click or even contextmenu events won't be enough. User could use shortcut keys to open link on new tab or even configure his browser for that. And i don't think it would be that easy to catch all possible cases

Comment: right now i am looking for only open link in new tab by right click only

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

You can not detect that, but you can detect the ctrl + click, cmd + click etc. something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="clickevent($event)">Opentab</a> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
        $scope.clickevent = function($event){
          if (event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || event.metaKey || $event.which == 2) {
            alert("aa");
          }

        }
    });
```

Hope it help, Cheers :)