# Use href with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a link that should call a $scope-function which causes another view to bei displayed.

But I also want that the User can rightclick onto that Link and open it into a new window or bookmark this.

So this is the (non-working) html:

```
<a ng-click="OpenSubsite(singleitem.Id)" href="{{GetUrl(singleItem.Id)}}">{{singleItem.Title}}</a>
```

The controller contains the following Code:

```
$scope.OpenSubSite=function(id) {
  $scope.LoadItem(id);
}
$scope.GetUrl=function(id) {
  return "showitem.html#id="+id;
}
```

Both methods alone work fine. Just not in the combination I want. I want the "`OpenSubSite()`" to be called when clicking onto that URL but when doing a rightclick ("open in new tab" or "add to favorites") the "`GetUrl()`"-Returnvalue should be used instead.

But with this code, the URL from GetUrl() is always opened even on left Mousebutton click,

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: consider using the directive in the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js

Comment: And what is the piece that doesn't work?

Comment: I guess this does not work. I want no custom RMB-action, but "just" the URL to be submitted to the browser

Comment: @devqon clearified that in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prevent the default action when you trigger the `ng-click`. You can do that by passing the [`$event` object of the `ng-click` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-):

```
<a ng-click="OpenSubsite($event, singleitem.Id)">..</a>
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.OpenSubSite = function(ev, id) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // prevent it opens default

    $scope.LoadItem(id);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is the "return false" also needed in that example?

Comment: Don't think its required, but it was always used in the past :) Maybe for oldtimers like IE

Answer (score 1):

you need to prevent the default

```
ng-click="OpenSubsite($event,singleitem.Id)"

$scope.OpenSubSite=function($event,id) {
   $event.preventDefault()
   $scope.LoadItem(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add onclick="return false;"

the html will be

```
<a ng-click="OpenSubsite(singleitem.Id)" onclick="return false;" href="{{GetUrl(singleItem.Id)}}">{{singleItem.Title}}</a>
```

this will prevent the clicking to redirect to GetUrl but it will work in  case you use open in new tab

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative answer:** You can get `$event` in ng-method and determine which button is clicked. After that, you can assign any method to related button like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {

    /*
      other methods like LoadItem
    */
    $scope.LoadItem = function(id) {
      //some stuf here
    }
    $scope.OpenSubSite=function(id) {
      $scope.LoadItem(id);
    };
    $scope.GetUrl=function(id) {
      return "showitem.html#id="+id;
    };
    $scope.handleClick = function(evt, id) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      switch(evt.which) {
        case 1:
            alert("left click");
            $scope.OpenSubSite(id);
            // this is left click
            break;
        case 3:
            alert("right click");
            $scope.GetUrl(id);
            // this is right click
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    <a href="#" ng-mousedown="handleClick($event, 1)">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```