# Call an Angular $scope.Function from href in current or new tab by right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click='redirectToEntity("B-",obj.id")'>Click me and Process function and then redirect</a>
```

This code does process function and redirect to page which I am targeting, but this does **not work** for **Open in new tab** by **right clicking**. I've tried numerous solution but none worked for me.
I need to execute redirectToEntity function only when clicked on "Open in New Tab".

Answer (score 1):

In order to let the normal right-click menu work, the `<a>` needs to be a regular anchor tag. So it can't be activated by `ng-click`. If all that `redirectToEntity()` does is generate a url and redirect from within the controller, maybe instead you should just generate the url and add it to the href like this `<a href="{{linkGeneratedInController}}">`.

Alternatively, you can also use a directive to bind an action to the right click, [as is shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732476/51).