# Detect Mouser right click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I implement this kind of situation using angularjs,I have a HTML element,it has style 'pointer-events: none' (because I need it for mouse left click) and I wandering how can I detect mouse right click on this element,any suggestion will be helpful for me. thanks : )

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand why this question doesn't meet our standards for completeness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle right-click events in angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js Google is your friend.

Comment: Won't register if you use `pointer-events:none`. Provide a [mcve]